VS Code. How to compile a given list of files?
There are several files in the project directory that need to be compiled using GCC. I want to create a tasks.json file that lists these files, so that I can use it in different compilation tasks. I also want to set a variable name at the beginning so that I can use it later. Below is the 'task.json' file, but of course it doesn't work because it can't have the "name" and "source-files" variables.
It seems to me that these variables are needed to specify a list of files that will be compiled. How to do it right?
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "name":projectname
    "source-files":
    [
        "1.for",
        "2.for"
    ],
    "tasks":
    [
        {
            "label": "build profile" ,
            "type": "shell" ,
            "command": "gfortran",
            "args":
            [
                "-pg",
                "-no-pie",
                "-Wall",
                "-o",
                "name-${label}.exe",
                "${source-files}"
            ],
            "group":
            {
                "kind":  "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "build debug" ,
            "type": "shell" ,
            "command": "gfortran",
            "args":
            [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "name-${label}.exe",
                "${source-files}"
            ],
            "group":
            {
                "kind":  "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "build release" ,
            "type": "shell" ,
            "command": "gfortran",
            "args":
            [
                "-O2",
                "-o",
                "name-${label}.exe",
                "${source-files}"
            ],
            "group":
            {
                "kind":  "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}


Seems like a couple different things in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference would work?

That said, I'd think twice before using tasks.json instead of Cmake/Makefile--if you want to share this code with others, it's better if they can compile it regardless of what text editor they use. And if you need to switch text editors in the future, you won't be unable to build this project. (I found this out the hard way when the Atom editor died.)
